# Why is my requestPayload empty on my ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

We are trying to migrate from pure `ext.js` to a model that uses `ext.js` in the controller, but front end is pure html, bootstrap.

As we migrate, I am trying to make a ajax on a login request. I have a ajax call which is returning a empty `requestPayload`.

```
loginSubmit : function(param){
        var me = this,
        params = {
            url: 'login/login',
            method: "POST",
            jsonData: Ext.JSON.encode(param.formValues) ,
            success: function (response) {
                var data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                Insights.view.common.util.StorageUtil.setAppData(response.responseText);

                me.getView().destroy();

                Ext.create({
                    xtype: 'mainviewport'
                });
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                var errorMessage = "Network connect timeout error"
                if (response.status == 401 || response.status == 500) {
                    var data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                    errorMessage = data.message;
                }

                if(param.loginButton){
                    var errMsg = form.queryById('login-error-msg');
                    errMsg.setText(errorMessage);
                    errMsg.setVisible(true);
                    param.loginButton && params.loginButton.enable();
                }

            }
        };
        Insights.view.common.util.RequestUtil.request(params, 'false');
    },
```

I did a debug on Chrome and the requestPayload does not exist.

[image: not working html version]

The pure ext.js project returns the following on debug on Chrome.

[image: working extjs version]

As you notice, this has the requestPayload with the username and password. Also `failure: function (response)` **returns response.status=0**. What am I missing in the pure javascript way of sending the request.

**EDIT, adding RequestUtil Code**

```
Ext.define('Insights.view.common.util.RequestUtil', {
    singleton: true,

    config: {
        baseUrl: ''
    },

    request: function (params, component) {
        var me = this,
            headers = {
                'ACCEPT': 'application/json'
            };


        var appData = Insights.view.common.util.StorageUtil.getAppData();
        if (appData) {
            headers.authToken = appData.token;
        } else if (params.authToken) {
            headers.authToken = params.authToken;
        }

        if(params.headers) {
            Ext.Object.merge(headers, params.headers)
        }

        this.loadMask(component);
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: this.getBaseUrl() + params.url,
            timeout: 60000,
            headers: headers,
            disableCaching: false,
            method: params.method,
            jsonData: params.jsonData,
            params: params.extraParams,
            binary: !params.binary ? false : params.binary,
            success: function (response, opts) {
                if (params.success) {
                    params.success(response, opts);
                    me.unLoadMask(component);
                }
            },
            failure: function (response, opts) {
                if (params.failure) {
                    params.failure(response, opts);
                }

                if (!Ext.isString(component)) {
                    me.unLoadMask(component);
                    if (params.url == "authenticate" || params.url == "userInfo") {
                        return;
                    }
                    var responseText = response.responseText && Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                    if (responseText && responseText.status === 'Failure') {
                        Ext.Msg.alert(i18nLabels.warning, responseText.message);
                    } else if (response.status == 401) {
                        me.handleSessionTimeout();
                    } else if (response.status == 404 || response.status == 500) {
                        me.errorHandler(responseText.message);
                    } else if (response.status == 405) {
                    } else {
                        me.errorHandler(i18nLabels.serverNotAvailable);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    },
```

I debugged and checked, jsonData does have the username,password string. This ajax fails and enters `failure` segment.

Comment: I have a feeling that is CORS related. In you first screenshot there is a preflight OPTIONS request, while in the second it's a simple POST. Check that `this.getBaseUrl()` returns the same domain as the current application domain or if it should be different - enable CORS.

Comment: your hint helped me, please put a answer, open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="tmp/tmpChrome" solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OPTIONS request in the first screen suggests that there is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) related problem. This problem can be solved by [enabling CORS](https://enable-cors.org/).

**Author's solution (from comments):** `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="tmp/tmpChrome`